# Range of Values for Random Forest Mean Decrease in Accuracy

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

When calculating variable importance using the unscaled (Scale= FALSE) permutation variable importance, what is the range of values you can get? Is it expressed as a percent (e.g. a value of 0.1 represents a 0.1% decrease in accuracy) or as a proportion (e.g. a value of 0.1 represents a 10% decrease in accuracy).From a bit of playing around with it I can't get the values to be higher that 1, so I believe it is the latter option but couldn't find confirmation anywhere. I am using the randomForest package in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that it should be interpreted as a percentage. In other words, accuracy changing from 0.08 to 0.06 should be interpreted as a change in accuracy by an average of 2% (average taken across the trees that make up the forest). Here is a link, together with an accompanying paper that you might consult:

https://bigdata.unl.edu/documents/ASA_Workshop_Materials/Why%20and%20how%20to%20use%20random%20forest%20variable%20importance%20measures.pdf

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1796903/